# What is the difference between didChangeDependencies and initState?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and when I want to call my context in InitState it throws an error :
which is about
`BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType`
but then I use didChangeDependencies and it works correctly.

Now I have 2 question:

1- Why calling our context in initState does not work but it works when calling from didChangeDependencies ?
(because as I read in official doc `This method is also called immediately after [initState]`,
and both of them will be called before build method. )

2- Why do we have access to our context outside of build method ( because there we have `build(BuildContext context)` and we can use our context but in didChangeDependencies we don't have anything like `didChangeDependencies(BuildContext context)` , so from where can we call context to use it) ?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

> Context of a state is available to us from the moment the State loads its dependencies.

At the time build is called, `context` is available to us and is passed as an argument.

Now moving on,
`initstate` is called before the state loads its dependencies and for that reason no context is available and you get an error for that if you use context in *initstate*.
However, `didChangeDependencies` is called just a few moments after the state loads its dependencies and context is available at this moment so here you can use context.

> However both of them are called before `build` is called.
> The only difference is that one is called before the state loads its dependencies and the other is called a few moments after the state loads its dependencies.

Comment: Quick question @SanjaySingh initState gets called only one time, what about didChangeDependencies? Because i have found myself in a continuous loop when i use it! Thanks in advance for your answer!

Comment: @abrsh Hey look, initstate is called only once when we firstly initialize the data. we cannot call initstate again and again to update the data because no context is there so it doesn't knows which data to update (i.e. initialize again). So to remove this problem we have didchangedependencies which have the context and knows which data to update. So YES we can call didchangedependencies again and again to update/initialize our data

Answer (score 24):

I've found a significant difference between `initState` and `didChangeDependencies`:

- `initState` is called only **once** for a widget.
- `didChangeDependencies` may be called **multiple times** per widget lifecycle (in my case it was called when the keyboard appears / disappears)

Answer (score 15):

`initState()` Called when new Widget is inserted into the tree.
The framework will call this method exactly once for each [State] object
it creates. This will be called once so perform work which required to be performed only once, but remember `context` can't be used here, as widget state gets loaded only `initState()` work is done.

**Syntax:**

```
@override
  void initState() {
    debugPrint('initState()');
    super.initState();
  }
```

`didChangeDependencies()` Called when a dependency of this [State] object changes.

So, exactly **How it gets called?** as by the above definition, it looks like it will be called after state changes but how we come to know the state is changed?

**Example:**

The below example uses the `Provider` state management mechanism to update the child widget from the parent widget. The `Provider` has an attribute called `updateShouldNotify` which decides whether to state is changed or not. If it's returning `true` then only `didChangeDependencies` gets called in `ChildWidget` class.

updateShouldNotify is returning true by default internally, as it knows the state got changed. **Then Why we need updateShouldNotify?** it's need because if someone wants to update the state on a specific condition,
Eg: if UI required to show only `even` values then we can add a condition like

```
updateShouldNotify: (oldValue, newValue) => newValue % 2 == 0,
```

**Code Snippet:**

```
class ParentWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  ParentWidget({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _ParentWidgetState createState() => _ParentWidgetState();
}

class _ParentWidgetState extends State<ParentWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Life Cycle'),
      ),
      body: Provider.value(
        value: _counter,
        updateShouldNotify: (oldValue, newValue) => true,
        child: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                'Press Fab button to increase counter:',
              ),
              ChildWidget()
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: _incrementCounter,
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class ChildWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChildWidgetState createState() => _ChildWidgetState();
}

class _ChildWidgetState extends State<ChildWidget> {
  int _counter = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState(), counter = $_counter');
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    _counter = Provider.of<int>(context);
    print('didChangeDependencies(), counter = $_counter');
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build(), counter = $_counter');
    return Text(
      '$_counter',
    );
  }
}
```

**Output Logs:**

```
I/flutter ( 3779): didChangeDependencies(), counter = 1
I/flutter ( 3779): build(), counter = 1
```

**For detail explanation:**

https://medium.com/@jitsm555/differentiate-between-didchangedependencies-and-initstate-f98a8ae43164?sk=47b8dda310f307865d8d3873966a9f4f

Comment: very good explanation, can I ask you that is it possible that ```didChangeDependencies``` method called in another situation, means it will be called only if updateShouldNotify returned true ?

Answer (score 6):

`initState()` is the first method called after a widget is created. This is similar to
`onCreate()` in Android or `viewDidLoad()` in iOS.

The first time the framework builds a widget, it calls `didChangeDependencies()`
after `initState()`. It might call `didChangeDependencies()` again if your state
object depends on an inherited widget that has changed.

[image]

source: [Flutter apprentice published by kodeco](https://www.kodeco.com/books/flutter-apprentice/v3.0#:%7E:text=Android%20with%20Flutter!-,Flutter%20is%20a%20new%20and%20exciting%20software%20development%20toolkit%20that,declarative%20approach%20to%20UI%20development.)

Answer (score 4):

1. [According to `initState` documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/initState.html)

> You cannot use `BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` from this method. However, `didChangeDependencies` will be called immediately following this method, and `BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` can be used there.

So you need to use `BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType` in `didChangeDependencies`.

2. Every Widget has its own `context`. That is why you have access to context outside build method.

Regarding `build(BuildContext context)`, `build` method accepts `context` from the parent widget. It means this parameter `BuildContext context` is not current widget's context but its parent's context.

Comment: Thanks, I understand the second answer , but not the first, I know this behavior but What is the reason?

Comment: didChangeDependencies will be called immediately following initState, ok but why we can't use BuildContext.inheritFromWidgetOfExactType in initState? (I am enthusiastic for reason not the behavior)

Answer (score 4):

The notion of `context` being mysteriously accessible outside `build()` was the one that bugged me. I think clarifying this subtle point supplements explanations given in other answers about the first question.

#### How is `context` accessible from outside the `build()` method?

The confusion stems from the (wrong) assumption that `context` needed to be passed to [`State.build()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) at all. Note that the [`State`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State-class.html) class already has a `context` property and according to the documentation, it is *redundantly provided* to [`build()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/build.html) here, so that its signature matches that of a [`WidgetBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetBuilder.html). However, this is not the same `build()` method as that of a [`StatelessWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatelessWidget-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

*This is a supplemental answer showing what the OP described.*

The `State` class of a `StatefulWidget` has a `context` property. This build context is first available in `didChangeDependencies`. Trying to use `context` in `initState` will cause an error.

```
class HomeWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeWidget({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeWidgetState createState() => _HomeWidgetState();
}

class _HomeWidgetState extends State<HomeWidget> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    print('initState');
    // print(Theme.of(context));        // ERROR!
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    print('didChangeDependencies');
    print(Theme.of(context));           // OK
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('build');
    print(Theme.of(context));           // OK
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Running that gives the print statements in the following order:

```
initState
didChangeDependencies
ThemeData#93b06
build
ThemeData#93b06
```

See also [Working with didChangeDependencies() in Flutter](https://www.kindacode.com/article/working-with-didchangedependencies-in-flutter/)

Comment: If I call a Provider to get information and set it to variable then will we need to call setState() after assigning value to variable which will be used in build to show updates? eg. code is as: `@override
  void didChangeDependencies() {
    chatMsgList = Provider.of<ChatUserConversationProvider>(context).getChatUserConversationList;
    setState(() {});
    super.didChangeDependencies();
  }` Kindly confirm and share your suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Called when a dependency of this State object changes.

For example, if the previous call to build referenced an **InheritedWidget** that later changed, the framework would call this method to notify this object about the change.

This method is also called immediately after **initState**. It is safe to call **BuildContext.dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType** from this method.

In fact Subclasses rarely override this method because the framework always calls build after a dependency changes. Some subclasses do override this method because they need to do some expensive work (e.g., network fetches) when their dependencies change, and that work would be too expensive to do for every build.

Answer (score -4):

you can still use context in initState() method, its hack buts works, all you need to do is sought of delay whatever you will need to execute that has context in it like so:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    Future.delayed(Duration.zero).then((_) {
      // you code with context here
    });
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: The post isn't about how to get the `BuildContext` inside`initState`.