# Async Calls to get some data from Route params

Tags: flutter

There is a little confusion on my part.  Let's say I have a stateful widget that needs to get some data.  The docs state that this is not recommended for the build method so I put it in the `initState`.  This is documented [here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/networking/fetch-data#why-is-fetchalbum-called-in-initstate).

I have also implemented the named routing from the documentation examples here which are done with stateless widgets.  [Article reference here](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments).

When I try to access the route parameters the `initState` it throws an error. The error is specifically thrown on the ModelRoute call.

```
@override
void initState() {

 super.initState();
 TownDetailPageArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
}
```

[[image]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlLfo.png)

If that code is moved to the build method it works fine.

So, my question is, what is the recommended way get access to the route parameters to use to get data in a stateful widget?

Comment: see [Alternatively, extract the arguments using onGenerateRoute](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigate-with-arguments#alternatively-extract-the-arguments-using-ongenerateroute)

Comment: I'm thinking I'll need to do it this way.  The other solution fires when the route is popped which i don't want to do so passing them in seems the way to go here.  I'll test it out.

Comment: One wonders why the downvotes but tis the season I guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `context` available in the `initState` method, which is necessary to pass in order to use the `of` method. You should instead use the similar method [`didChangeDependencies`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/State/didChangeDependencies.html), which does have access to the `context`. The differences between the two can be read about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58668378/13250142).

Example usage (identical to `initState` just called a bit later):

```
@override
void didChangeDependencies() {

 super.didChangeDependencies();
 TownDetailPageArguments args = ModalRoute.of(context).settings.arguments;
}
```

Comment: I noticed the back arrow in the app bar when touched fires this method which seems pretty inefficient to me.

Comment: That's necessary as it means the InheritedWidget is updated. Alternatively you could do it in initState with a a delay, but it will not be updated when the property you're reading changes. This is the best method for what you're trying to do. Doing this in the build method or having it called in didChangeDependencies isn't as bad as you might think as this likely isn't a very expensive operation.